# How to edit Windows 10 login screen so that it will only work if there is a working usb camera installed?

Tags: windows, winlogon

How can I edit Windows 10 login screen so that it will only work if there is a working usb camera installed?  Is there any documentation of API example or tool for this use case?

Comment: Gina support ended with server 2003. The new login credential providers in Vista probably don't give you enough control.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement and use a combination of your own couple of [Credential Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nn-credentialprovider-icredentialprovider) and [Credential Provider Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nn-credentialprovider-icredentialproviderfilter).

Inside of [ICredentialProviderFilter::Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialproviderfilter-filter) method you can make a decision to enable or disable any Credential Provider.

Inside of [ICredentialProvider::SetUsageScenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialprovider-setusagescenario) method you also can make a decision to show or to hide your own Provider.
Here you also can create and show a dummy tile with "Please connect USB-camera" caption on it.